# "Protocol error in TDS stream" when trying to connect to MySQL server

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pypyodbc

I am trying to connect with Python to my MySQL server which I run on another PC.
The server works fine and I am able to connect to it with HeidiSQL client.

But when I try to do it with Python with the following code:

```
import pypyodbc
connection_string2='Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=LinuxPC,3306;Database=sqldb;uid=sqlusr;pwd=usrpasswd;'
connection2 = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string2)
```

I get this error:

> Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Protocol error in TDS stream')

Any advice for me?

PS: if it is important I had installed ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server and `Driver={SQL Server}` does not work

Comment: You're trying to use a SQL Server driver for MySQL? That won't work of course. Use a MySQL driver instead.

Comment: @stickybit thanks a lot! With mysql.connector it works. Is there any way to make it work with pypyodbc?

Comment: Probably with an ODBC MySQL driver.